# Async method with no await

Tags: .net, .net-core

is it correct to have a "branch" without `await` operator inside an asynchronous method?

```
    public async Task<Person> GetName(string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            return null;
        }
        return await _database.Logins.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Name.Contains(name));
    }
```

[Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) says

> async methods need to have an await keyword in their body or they will
>   never yield!
>
> If await is not used in the body of an async method, the C#
>   compiler will generate a warning, but the code will compile and run as
>   if it were a normal method. Note that this would also be incredibly
>   inefficient

Does this apply to my method as it contains `await`, but not in every branch

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `async` decorated methods then the compiler will transform `null` into `Task.FromResult<Person>(null)`.

If your method has an `await` in it's body then the compiler will actually generate a class that is a state machine that keeps track of all the `await` continuations, so your code runs as intended after each task completion that you wait for. The state machine class will preserve any variables and stack.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's perfectly acceptable to have some paths within an `async` method that are in fact synchronous.

You would only generally want to have such paths (as in your sample) where they are "fast" success/failure paths and it's only the "slow" path(s) that can actually benefit from using `await`.